# Azure Drive addressing using local emulated blob store

Tags: azure

I am unable to get a simple tech demo working for Azure Drive using a locally hosted service running the storage/compute emulator. This is not my first azure project, only my first use of the Azure Drive feature.

The code:

```
var localCache = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MyAzureDriveCache"); 
CloudDrive.InitializeCache(localCache.RootPath, localCache.MaximumSizeInMegabytes);
var creds = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey("devstoreaccount1", "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==");
drive = new CloudDrive(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/drive"), creds);
drive.CreateIfNotExist(16);
drive.Mount(0, DriveMountOptions.None);
```

With local resource configuration:

```
LocalStorage name="MyAzureDriveCache" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" sizeInMB="220000"
```

The exception:

```
Uri http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/drive is Invalid
```

Information on how to address local storage can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/

I have used the storage emulator UI to create the  C:\Users...\AppData\Local\dftmp\wadd\devstoreaccount1 folder which I would expect to act as the container in this case.

However, I am following those guidelines (as far as I can tell) and yet still I receive the exception. Is anyone able to identify what I am doing wrong in this case? I had hoped to be able to resolve this easily using a working sample where someone else is using CloudDrive with 127.0.0.1 or localhost but was unable to find such on Google.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have passed several required steps before mounting.

You have to initialize the local cache for the drive, and the URI of the page blob containing the Cloud Drive before mounting it.

**Initializing the cache:**

```
// Initialize the local cache for the Azure drive
LocalResource cache = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("LocalDriveCache");
CloudDrive.InitializeCache(cache.RootPath + "cache", cache.MaximumSizeInMegabytes);
```

**Defining the URI of the page blob, usually made in the configuration file:**

```
// Retrieve URI for the page blob that contains the cloud drive from configuration settings
string imageStoreBlobUri = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("< Configuration name>");
```

Comment: Hi Hhaggan, thanks for your feedback. I do actually have the cache initialisation but didn't include earlier for brevity; I have added it now. Would it be possible for you to include the "<Configuration name>" definition in your response (content from the configuration file)?

Comment: first of all sorry for the late reply, here is the what is missing <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
      <Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
      <Setting name="ImageStoreBlobUri" value="mydrives/SamplePictures.vhd" />
    </ConfigurationSettings> you can add this to your service configuration in the role tag.

Comment: I get errors when I place these values in my ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg because there is no matching values defined in the service definition file; do you have the matching definition elements by any chance? I apologise but C# is not my forte and this has been parked for a while now (not fresh in my mind). Cheers

Comment: did you try the work around before, go to your role and enter the settings manually don't write them.  go to the role properties, add new setting for this configuration setting keep it as a string and in the value add the URL which in my last comment was "mydrives/SamplePictures.vhd".